# How to sort dataset based on 2 custom lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sort df based on 2 custom dictionaries:

```
custom_dict = {'HC': 0, 'AMG HC': 1, 'S': 2, 'AMG S': 3,
               'HCA':4, 'AMG HCA':5, 'MUP':6, 'AMG MUP':7}
custom_dict2 = {'Offline': 0, 'Online': 1, 'Independent':2}
df4 = df4.sort_values(by=['category','segment'], key=lambda x: x.map(custom_dict, custom_dict2))
```

The I execute this code:

```
df4 = (df4.set_index(['category', 'segment'], append=True)
   .unstack()
   .swaplevel(axis=1)
   .sort_index(level=0, axis=1, ascending=False)
   .reindex([ytd1, ytd2, 'Evolution'], level=1, axis=1)
   .reset_index('category')
#   .sort_index(level=-1, axis=0)
    )
```

But it doesn't print the expected output. I want to have the following order: HC from Offline, AMG HC from Offline, HC from Online, AMG HC from Online, HC from Independent, AMG HC from Independent, S from Online, AMF from Online etc.

Can you please help me how to do this?

Sample of dataset:

```
df4 = {'category': {0: 'HC', 1: 'AMG HC', 2: 'S', 3: 'AMG MUP', 4: 'MUP', 5: 'S', 6: 'AMG S', 7: 'HCA'}, 'segment': {0: 'Offline', 1: 'Offline', 2: 'Offline', 3: 'Offline', 4: 'Online', 5: 'Online', 6: 'Offline', 7: 'Independent'}, 'ytd2020': {0: '101142', 1: '38541', 2: '55653', 3: '19561', 4: '84921', 5: '99301', 6: '80212', 7: '95731'}, 'ytd2021': {0: '105726', 1: '39463', 2: '57537', 3: '21402', 4: '90310', 5: '97283', 6: '87011', 7: '119289'}, 'Evolution': {0: '4.5%', 1: '2.4%', 2: '2.1%', 3: '4.3%', 4: '8.2%', 5: '-2.0%', 6: '12.4%', 7: '24.6%'}}
```

Comment: could you be more specific about the output order. A table would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` function in `sort_values` is supposed to be applied to the columns `category` and `segment` individually, but you are instead trying to map both the columns in one go which is producing the incorrect output. In order to fix your code we can create an additional `order` dictionary which helps us map the column names to the corresponding mapping dictionary

```
order = {'category': custom_dict, 'segment': custom_dict2}
df4.sort_values(['category', 'segment'], key=lambda s: s.map(order[s.name]))
```

---

```
  category      segment ytd2020 ytd2021 Evolution
0       HC      Offline  101142  105726      4.5%
1   AMG HC      Offline   38541   39463      2.4%
2        S      Offline   55653   57537      2.1%
5        S       Online   99301   97283     -2.0%
6    AMG S      Offline   80212   87011     12.4%
7      HCA  Independent   95731  119289     24.6%
4      MUP       Online   84921   90310      8.2%
3  AMG MUP      Offline   19561   21402      4.3%
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set you data as [ordered categories](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html). There are several advantages, smaller memory consumption and faster sorting once the categories are in place:

```
df4['category'] = pd.Categorical(df4['category'],
                                 categories=list(custom_dict),
                                 ordered=True)
df4['segment'] = pd.Categorical(df4['segment'],
                                categories=list(custom_dict2),
                                ordered=True)

df4 = df4.sort_values(by=['category','segment'])
```

*NB. you don't need a dictionary for this solution, a list with the categories in the desired order is sufficient*

example output (from random input):

```
   category      segment
11       HC      Offline
14       HC      Offline
1        HC       Online
5        HC  Independent
16       HC  Independent
19   AMG HC      Offline
15   AMG HC       Online
3         S      Offline
4         S      Offline
0         S  Independent
12        S  Independent
9     AMG S       Online
10    AMG S  Independent
2       HCA      Offline
6       HCA      Offline
17      HCA  Independent
7   AMG HCA      Offline
13  AMG HCA  Independent
8       MUP       Online
18  AMG MUP  Independent
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding from your previous question, your primary goal is to place all `AMG XXX` immediately following the corresponding `XXX` category for the same segment.  E.g. `AMG HC` to **immediately follow** `HC` in `offline` segment and `AMG S` to **immediately follow** `S` in the same `offline` segment.

As such, you can use:

```
idx = (df4[['category','segment']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
                                  .sort_values(key=lambda x: x.str[0].map(custom_dict) * 10 + x.str[1].map(custom_dict2))
                                  .index
      )

df5 = df4.loc[idx]
```

Note that I have placed the sorted dataframe into a new name `df5` instead of overwriting `df4`.  You are free to change this `df5` to `df4` if it is more convenient to you.

**Result:**

```
print(df5)


  category      segment ytd2020 ytd2021 Evolution
0       HC      Offline  101142  105726      4.5%
1   AMG HC      Offline   38541   39463      2.4%
2        S      Offline   55653   57537      2.1%
5        S       Online   99301   97283     -2.0%
6    AMG S      Offline   80212   87011     12.4%
7      HCA  Independent   95731  119289     24.6%
4      MUP       Online   84921   90310      8.2%
3  AMG MUP      Offline   19561   21402      4.3%
```